# Starting X applications over ssh on the local monitor

Tags: ssh, camera, xorg

If I have a Pi with monitor connected but no keyboard or mouse how can I remote in to the Pi over the net with ssh to start applications running on the attached monitor. In particular, I have a hq camera mounted on the pi to which I intend to attach a small screen to monitor the focus of an attached Canon telephoto. Note I’m not intending to view the image, just a representation of how well the image is focussed using OpenCV, so a small TFT would suffice but I do need to remote in to start the app on screen and fiddle with it as necessary.

Comment: Why not use VNC?

Comment: That’s a possibility but not perfect, since I’d want to be able to connect out in the wild using something like a mobile phone ssh app. I could use vnc on a phone but it’s not an ideal interface for what I want.

Comment: You need to have the GUI running, then you can launch applications in it by setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable, which you can get by checking in a GUI terminal (`echo $DISPLAY`).  Chances are it is just `:0`.

Comment: Not that simple, you can achieve that via ssh -Y name@host but applications then run as a child of the ssh session which once terminated terminates it’s children. And more to the point if I run ssh as above and execute a command using X it runs on the remote machine but displays on the machine originating ssh. What I need is the reverse to ssh into machine X from Y, run the application with X using its own server and not Y’s server but still taking keyboard input from Y’s server.

Comment: Could be a job for [`x2x`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x2x).